# QGIS: How to modify the appearence of selected attributes

Tags: qgis, symbology, select-by-attribute, color

I am using QGIS version 2.14.1 (Essen). When I open the attributes table of a layer, I select some data which is then highlighted in yellow on the map. I was wondering if it is possible to change the appearance of this yellow (play with the transparency or colour)?

The other idea is to create a single shapefile from all the different attributes but that would take too long as I have lots of data.

Anyone know if this is possible in QGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No menu: Project >> Project Properties >> Selection color:

[image]

Comment: this is fine to change the colour but I cant change the transparency. Anyway to also change the transparency?

Comment: @philippe - If you click the down arrow next to the yellow colour shown in the image, you can choose some options such as `Copy colour`, `Pick colour` etc. Select `Choose colour` and from here you can set the colour and its transparency (or opacity).

Comment: Ah perfect thanks, its under opacity not transparency