# QGIS: How to modify the selection style when selecting features in a standalone script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, standalone

It's quite easy to modify the default style that QGIS applies when selecting attributes in the GUI by following the steps in this question: [QGIS: How to modify the appearence of selected attributes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192254/qgis-how-to-modify-the-appearence-of-selected-attributes)

However, when working with a stand-alone script that opens the same project, selects a feature and exports the contents of the bounding box to a png, the selection style is still the same default yellow.

For rendering and saving, I'm following the steps described in the [QGIS Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html). The only addition is feature selection and setting extents to feature bounding box.

I probably have to set the style explicitly in a stand-alone script. How to accomplish that?

EDIT: MINIMAL REPRODUCE

**Step 1**: modify selected feature style in project

**Step 2**: load project and try to render layer with the following code

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.read('/where/my/project/at')


vlayer = project.mapLayersByName('MY_LAYER')[0]
vlayer.selectByIds([my_id])
settings = QgsMapSettings()
settings.setLayers([vlayer])
settings.setBackgroundColor(QColor(255, 255, 255))
settings.setOutputSize(QSize(800, 600))
settings.setExtent(vlayer.extent())

render = QgsMapRendererParallelJob(settings)
    image_location = os.path.join(QgsProject.instance().homePath(), "render.png")

def finished():
    img = render.renderedImage()
    # save the image; e.g. img.save("/Users/myuser/render.png","png")
    img.save(image_location, "png")

render.finished.connect(finished)

# Start the rendering
render.start()

# The following loop is not normally required, we
# are using it here because this is a standalone example.
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QEventLoop
loop = QEventLoop()
render.finished.connect(loop.quit)
loop.exec_()
```

**Step 3**: feature selected but selection color still standard QGIS yellow.

Comment: Could you please add a minimal working example of the script so that we can working on it? Did you try [`project.setSelectionColor(...)`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html#a40ea11a42e358dd4225d55bc526a2787)?

Comment: Sure thing! Will add code.

Answer (score 3):

In the end [Kadir's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/29431/kadir-%C5%9Eahbaz) comment pointed me to the right direction. Using `project.setSelectionColor(...)` did not change the color of the selection in the renderer but setting the style explicitly on the `QgsMapSettings()` did!

So by just adding `settings.setSelectionColor(QColor(255, 0, 0, 50))` to my code I got the nice transparent red I was looking for.